# Prove the Extended Pigeonhole Principle with Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction, solution-verification

I'm doing some exercises in proof-by-induction, and came across one where I need to prove both the Pigeonhole and the Extended Pigeonhole Principles. I've proved the former, and now I'm working to prove the latter, but I'm a little bit.

The Extended Pigeonhole Principle:

> For any finite sets $X$ and $Y$ and any positive integer $|X| > k \cdot |Y|$, if $f: X \rightarrow Y$, then there are at least $k + 1$ distinct members $x_1, \dots, x_{k + 1} \in X$ such that $f(x) = \dots = f(x_{k+1})$.

My approach was to use $k$ as the induction variable, and basically to say whenever this is true  for $k$, you can extend $X$ with $|Y|$ new elements, arbitrarily mapping them to elements in $Y$, and show that the principle must be true for $k + 1$. I've already proven the (Non-extended) Pigeonhole Principle, so where my proof makes use of it, I think that is considered OK.

My proof:

[image]

Clearly the *Otherwise* section is bogus and incomplete. As you can see, I'm trying to show that if the maximum cardinality of all $s \in S$ is $k + 1$, then no matter how you you add $|Y|$ new elements to these subsets, in the end you'll end up with at least one $s \in S$ such that $|s| = k + 2.

I can see this practically, e.g., consider $|X| = 11 and |Y| = 5$, such that $|X| > 2 \cdot |Y|$. Consider the sets $S$ and $A$, as mentioned in the proof. If you listed out the cardinalities of the sets in $S$, some possibilities are:

- $\{\{x_1, \dots, x_{k + 1}\}, \{x_1, \dots, x_k\}, \{x_1, \dots, x_k\}, \{x_1, \dots, x_k\}, \{x_1, \dots, x_k\}\}$
- $\{\{x_1, \dots, x_{k + 1}\}, \{x_1, \dots, x_{k + 1}\}, \{x_1, \dots, x_k\}, \{x_1, \dots, x_k\}, \{x_1, \dots, x_{k - 1}\}\}$
- $\{\{x_1, \dots, x_{k + 1}\}, \{x_1, \dots, x_{k + 1}\}, \{x_1, \dots, x_{k + 1}\}, \{x_1, \dots, x_k\}, \{x_1, \dots, x_{k - 2}\}\}$
- $\{\{x_1, \dots, x_{k + 1}\}, \{x_1, \dots, x_{k + 1}\}, \{x_1, \dots, x_{k + 1}\}, \{x_1, \dots, x_{k + 1}\}, \{x_1, \dots, x_{k - 3}\}\}$

Now take any one of the sets above, and consider dispersing $5$ new elements amongst any of its subsets. I'm trying to show that:

- If you add an an element to a set that already has $k + 1$ elements, of course the new cardinality will be $k + 2$, and the proof is done
- However if you avoid touching all sets with cardinalities $k + 1$, then you'll add enough elements to the other sets such that one will end up with $k + 2$ elements.

Any ideas how I can formally prove this?

Comment: I think you can use the pigeon hole principle itself to prove this.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach is to prove the contrapositive: if $|\{x\in X:f(x)=y\}|\le k$ for each $y\in Y$, then $|X|\le k|Y|$. This is immediate, since then

$$|X|\le\sum_{y\in Y}|\{x\in X:f(x)=y\}\le k|Y|\;.$$

**Added:** There is no good reason to prove the result by induction, and I think it poor pædagogy to require such a proof, but since that seems to be desired, here is one possibility that actually uses the induction hypothesis directly.

The base case is just the pigeonhole principle, which we are assuming. Now take as induction hypothesis the assertion that if $X$ and $Y$ are any finite sets such that $|X|>k|Y|$, and $f:X\to Y$ is any function from $X$ to $Y$, then there are at least $k+1$ distinct $x_1,\ldots,x_{k+1}\in X$ such that $f(x_1)=\ldots=f(x_{k+1})$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets such that $|X|>(k+1)|Y|$, and let $f:X\to Y$ be a function.

Let $Y_0=\operatorname{ran}f=f[X]$, for each $y\in Y_0$ choose an $x_y\in X$ such that $f(x_y)=y$ and let $X_0=\{x_y:y\in Y_0\}$. Now let $X_1=X\setminus X_0$; clearly $|X_0|\le|Y|$, so $|X_1|>(k+1)|Y|-|Y_0|\ge k|Y|$, and by the induction hypothesis there are a $y\in Y$ and distinct $x_1,\ldots,x_{k+1}\in X_1$ such that $f(x_1)=\ldots=f(x_{k+1})=y$. But then $\{x_y,x_1,\ldots,x_{k+1}\}$ is a set of $k+2$ distinct members of $X$ such that $f(x_y)=f(x_1)=\ldots=f(x_{k+1})$, as desired, and by induction the result holds for all $k\in\Bbb Z^+$.

Comment: Ah, OK yeah that seems pretty simple, thanks! But you'd probably want to replace $k$ with $k + 1$ right, since we're trying to show after adding $Y$ elements to $|X| > k \cdot |Y|$, there must be an $s \in S$ such that $|s| > k + 1$?

Comment: @DominicFarolino: No, I really do want $k$. I’m showing that if the function $f$ is at most $k$-to-$1$, then $X$ has at most $k|Y|$ elements. It immediately follows that if $X$ has more than $k|Y|$ elements, then some $y\in Y$ is $f(x)$ for more than $k$ elements of $X$.

Comment: Hmm, I think we already know that, because we use the Inductive Hypothesis to show that there's a $y \in Y$ that's $f(x)$ for $k + 1\ x \in X$. So what we're trying to prove is that if you add another $|Y|$ elements to $X'$, then there must be a $y \in Y$ that's $f(x)$ for $k + 2\ x \in X$

Comment: @DominicFarolino: There is no inductive hypothesis: mine is not a proof by induction. Induction is utterly unnecessary, and any exercise that requires it is a very poor exercise. However, if that is really required I can add a proof by induction.

Comment: I see, I thought you were saying I could use your statement in my "Inductive Step", but you're using your statement as a proof alone. Yeah, the exercise requires induction unfortunately, I guess for "extra" induction practice? Either way, I've worked your statement into my "Inductive Statement" with $k + 1$ which seems to do the trick. It does feel like I'm fighting myself trying to do this with induction though.

Comment: @DominicFarolino: I’ve added an induction argument that really does use its induction hypothesis.

Comment: Very good proof, thanks, I couldn't quite figure out how to use the I.H. like that. I've simplified my original proof, could you critique it? https://gist.github.com/domfarolino/17886dccf11d8d86be750ad2d2abcae3 I think it's valid, but feels weird that my I.S. starts from the I.H. and builds it up to the $k + 1$ case, instead of starting from the $k + 1$ and reducing it to the I.H.

Comment: @DominicFarolino: What you have there works as a proof of the theorem, but it isn’t actually a proof by induction, since the argument in the induction step makes no use of the induction hypothesis. You could present that argument without any reference to induction, and it would still prove the theorem. (I had to work a bit to find a genuine induction argument, one that actually used the induction hypothesis in an essential way.)

Comment: Makes sense, thanks a lot for spending the time on this.

Comment: @DominicFarolino: You’re welcome.